# How can rotate an elliptical animation path by a certain amount of degrees?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, kinematics

I'm using the following to get the x and y position of an entity as it travels along an elliptical path over time:

```
x = Math.cos(time)*width/2
y = Math.sin(time)*height/2
```

Is there a simple way to rotate the entire thing by a certain amount of degrees, say 45, or 132 for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a simple rotation transformation:

```
x1 = x*cos(a) - y*sin(a)
y1 = x*sin(a) + y*cos(a)
```

Where `a` - is the angle to rotate.

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) explains that in detail

Answer (score 1):

For each point(x, y) you calculated with above equation, you can rotate it theta degree(counter-clockwise) by the following equation

- x' = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
- y' = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);

where x and y are the original coordinates before rotation, x' and y' are the coordinates after rotation, theta is the angle to rotate.

[coordinate rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_rotations_and_reflections)

Comment: This seems like a good idea, but does not seem to work for me. I've updated my original post to include a code example.

Comment: var newX = x * Math.cos( this.angle ) - x * Math.sin( this.angle );
var newY = x * Math.sin( this.angle ) - y * Math.cos( this.angle ); This is not the equation what I mentioned above. is should be var newX = x * Math.cos( this.angle ) - y * Math.sin( this.angle );
var newY = x * Math.sin( this.angle ) - y * Math.cos( this.angle );

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just do a 2D rotation on the resulting `x` and `y` to rotate your ellipse:

```
xrot = x * cos(A) - y * sin(A)
yrot = x * sin(A) + y * cos(A)
```

And remember that `Radians = Degrees * PI / 180`.