# How come this simple rotation of an ellipse is rotating too much and distorting the dimensions?

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, shapes, kinematics

I'm [told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889334/how-can-rotate-an-elliptical-animation-path-by-a-certain-amount-of-degrees) by three different people that this is the correct way to rotate an ellipse:

```
// Get current position on the elliptical path.
var x = Math.cos( this.timer.delta() * this.speed ) * ( this.pathWidth / 2 );
var y = Math.sin( this.timer.delta() * this.speed ) * ( this.pathHeight / 2 );

// Rotate the ellipse.
var newX = x * Math.cos( this.angle ) - y * Math.sin( this.angle );
var newY = x * Math.sin( this.angle ) - y * Math.cos( this.angle );
```

I'm using a timer so that the position on the elliptical path cycles over time.

When this.angle = 0, there is no change to the path.

But when this.angle is greater than 0, the ellipse does not maintain it's proportions. It gets squished and pulled. And the differences between increments of a single degree are pretty severe.

**EDIT 1:**

Also, I would expect the path of when this.angle == 0 to be the same as when it is 180, 360, 540, 720, etc.

But they are all different.

**EDIT 2:**

Same behaviour despite the typo which has since been corrected.

**EDIT 3:**

Behaviour resolved by converting from degrees to radians and using them instead.

Like so:

```
this.angleRadians = this.angle * ( Math.PI / 180 );
```

Comment: Re edit 1: We would expect that it would be the same at 0 as it is at 2*pi, 4*pi, 6*pi, etc.

Comment: Oh really, is that to suggest that this.angle should be in radians, not degrees?

Comment: I think the last language I programmed in that used degrees for angles was Logo, and that was two-and-a-half decades ago.

Comment: Thanks so much for this question. This helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `newX` equation is wrong. You're missing `y`.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that in my original post. But that's not the problem. With the updated code, I still see nearly the exact same behaviour (ie. pretty random results).

Comment: I think that you are applying the rotation operator incorrectly. Check your signs and coordinate at `newX` (I think that it should be a `+y`).

Comment: It turns out I was using degrees when I should have been using radians. I'm marking this response as the correct one however, because it was a real typo I had overlooked.